# How to approach the into error problem in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

here is my code

```
begin
    open vcursor;
    loop
        fetch vcursor into v1, v2, v3, v4;
        exit when vcursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('hello');
        insert into tblproject
        select seq_tblproject.nextval, t5.SUBJECTNAME || 'project', T3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ
        into v1, v2, v3, v4
        from tblteam t1
                 inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
                 inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
                 inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
                 inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
                 inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ
        where (v1, v2) in (
            select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
            from tblteam t1
                     inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
                     inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
                     inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
                     inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
                     inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ);
--         dbms_output.PUT_LINE(a || ',' || b|| ',' ||c|| ',' ||d);

        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(v1);
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(v2);
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(v3);
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(v4);
    end loop;
end;
```

I want to debug with dbms output.

```
[65000][6550] 
ORA-06550: line 23, column 9: 
PL/SQL: ORA-01744: 
inappropriate INTO ORA-06550: line 21, column 9: 
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

An error like this appears.

It was confirmed that putting 4 values into insert into works normally with other code. But it's frustrating because it doesn't work in this code now.

How should I approach to solve this problem?
Oracle version is 11.g.

best regards

best regards

Comment: You're getting a compilation error.  `dbms_output` is something you call at runtime.  You can't use `dbms_output` to debug a compilation error.  Use `show errors` or query `user_errors` to see the compilation error(s).  I don't know what you want to happen with an `insert ... select ... into` statement.  You can have an `insert ... select` which inserts into the target table the results of the source `select` statement.  You can have a `select into` which selects a single row of data into scalar variables.  It doesn't make sense to try to combine those constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `SELECT INTO` statement and in `INSERT` statement mixed up and that is causing this error.
The statement starting with

```
insert into tblproject
```

and ending here

```
  inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ);
```

is the insert statement. Remove the line `into v1, v2, v3, v4` and it will work.
You cannot do a `SELECT INTO` in the middle of an insert statement. Hence the error `ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO`